# I want to have a output with 85 characters in each line, could you please say how I have to use print in this field?

Tags: perl

I used following command to get a specific format that the output of it is in one line:

```
MASH P 0 3.64 NAMD P 0 3.79 AGHA P 0 4.50 SARG P 0 4.71 BENG P 0 5.47 BANR P 0 6.75 ABZA P 0 6.25 KALI P 0 6.91
```

I want to have a output with 85 characters in each line, could someone explain how I have to use print in this field?

Comment: Do you have anything that you have tried yet? Are you having a problem with a particular part? Please include any examples of attempts that you have made to reach your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with a quantifier:

```
$_ = 'MASH P 0 3.64 NAMD P 0 3.79 AGHA P 0 4.50 SARG P 0 4.71 BENG P 0 5.47 BANR P 0 6.75 ABZA P 0 6.25 KALI P 0 6.91';
print $&, "\n" while /.{1,85}/g;
```

or, if it's a part of a larger program and you don't want to suffer the performance penalty, use `${^MATCH}` instead of `$&`:

```
use Syntax::Construct qw{ /p };
print ${^MATCH}, "\n" while /.{1,85}/gp;
```

You can also use the four argument `substr`:

```
print substr($_, 0, 85, q()), "\n" while $_;
```